# dictionaries with NaN key to pandas series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, series

I am trying to build a Pandas series by passing it a dictionary containing index and data pairs. While doing so I noticed an interesting quirk. When the dictionary contains `NaN` keys with an associated value, pandas Series retains the `NaN` key in the index but sets the corresponding value to `NaN` as well.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {np.nan: 3500.0, 66485174.0: 1.0}
d = pd.Series(d, dtype='float64')
```

In the example above, `3500.0` will be set to `NaN` by `pd.Series`.
I am using pandas 0.20.2 with python 2.7.

Does anyone know why this happens? My intuition is that `NaN` is probably seen as a infinite number beyond 64-bit, hence there might be some format issues

Comment: Not sure about the behavior. But, `pd.Series(d.values(), index=d.keys())` would work for you.

Comment: That is interesting!  I don't suspect it is intentional.  Confirmed @JohnGalt but I used `pd.Series(list(d.values()), index=d.keys())`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, it's odd. Also, pd.DataFrame function does not have the same problem: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index',dtype='float64')

Comment: Definitely fixed in pandas 0.23.3.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been fixed in pandas 0.23.3 (answered in comments).